# Network up to date when running migrate command

Tags: blockchain, truffle

When i run truffle migrate --network goerli i get the following output. Some days before I it compiled and runned fine and from nowhere the output came like this.

OUTPUT:
$ truffle migrate --network goerli

## Compiling your contracts...

> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\SmartGrid.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\asafy\ExjobbFinal\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:

- solc: 0.8.11+commit.d7f03943.Emscripten.clang
  Network up to date.

Looked around but didn't find anything helpful

Comment: When i try the command "truffle deploy" I get this error:

Comment: truffle deploy
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\SmartGrid.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\X\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.11+commit.d7f03943.Emscripten.clang
> Something went wrong while attempting to connect to the network at http://127.0.0.1:8545. Check your network configuration.
CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://127.0.0.1:8545.
Truffle v5.8.3 (core: 5.8.3)
Node v18.15.0